# QProcess не видит fpc после компиляции с pyinstaller (pyqt5, python3.7, macos)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, macos, qprocess

Вот кусок кода (упрощён):

```
...
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        ...

    def initUI(self):
        ...
        self.process = QProcess()
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.readyRead)
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.readyError)
        self.process.finished.connect(self.runBatch)
        ...
    def readyWrite(self):
        self.process.write(self.line.text().encode())
        self.process.write(b'\n')
        self.line.setText('')

    def readyError(self):
        self.out.append(bytes(self.process.readAllStandardError()).decode())

    def readyRead(self, *a):
        self.out.append(bytes(self.process.readAllStandardOutput()).decode())

    def runBatch(self):
        if self.__batch:
            cmd = self.__batch.pop(0)
            self.process.start(cmd, QProcess.Unbuffered | QProcess.ReadWrite)

    def run(self):
        os.system('rm -rf ./cached')
        os.system('mkdir ./cached')

        if self.process.state() == QProcess.NotRunning:
            with open('./cached/run.pas', 'w') as f:
                f.write(self.inp.toPlainText())

            self.out.setText('')
            self.__batch.append(self.compiler+' ./cached/run.pas')
            if platform.system() in ('Darwin', 'Linux'):
                self.__batch.append('./cached/run')
            else:
                self.__batch.append('cached/run.exe')

            self.runBatch()

        else:
            self.process.kill()
        ...
    ...
...
```

Собранный main.app с помощью `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --clean --noconfirm --osx-bundle-identifier=com.vosmottor.idepascal main.py` прекрасно работает, но при нажатии кнопки Run (вызывает `MainWindow.run()`) ничего не происходит. Ошибок не вызывает:
ничего не выводит ни в stderr, ни в stdin.

При компиляции я получаю .elf файл и .app.
.elf работает нормально. Но при запуске .app файла все работает кроме функции `MainWidnow.run()`. Я заметил, что если вызвать,
.elf файл, который находится в .app файле, то все тоже ок (то есть `./main.app/Contents/MacOS/main`). 
Поэтому  я решил, что проблема в `info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>main</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/MiniIDE/dist/main</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon-windowed.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.vosmottor.idepascal</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>main</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Почему ??? Как исправить ?

Comment: А если собрать без это флага --noconsole

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Toже самое.

Comment: Консоль появилась, но вывода нет?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin нет

Comment: Может pyinstaller забыл какой-то класс или dll-ку подсунуть. Попробуй распаковать и проверить. Или собрать без onefile

Comment: @eri Mac OS X .

Comment: Pyinstaller exe это самораспаковывающийся архив с зипом с py и дллками

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что криво отработал pyinstaller, могу порекомендовать поиграться с флагами, возможно, как было отмечено выше, проблема в том, что не был криво собран onefile